# Trying to add a video to a playlist (YouTube API v3)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, youtube-api

I am very frustrated with the YouTube API. I am trying to figure out how to add a video to a playlist.

Code: (To Get list of PlayList IDs?)

```
PlaylistsResource.ListRequest lr =   youtube.Playlists.List("id");
lr.Mine = true;
var PlayListResponse =  lr.Execute();
```

Once I have the playlist id:

```
var playlistItemsListRequest = youtube.PlaylistItems.Insert({id : id});
playlistItemsListRequest.Insert();
```

I'm I on the right track?

Comment: What's the problem/exception, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing [playlistItems->insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert).

First id you will set in that call is the playlist id.

Second is the resource id, actually videoId for that use case.

Comment: You can do a playlist search with search->list if you don't know the playlist id

Comment: I can't use search--> list to search my own playlist. I am trying to find a particular playlist to add the video to. All I know is the name of the playlist.

Comment: It's hanging on the .Execute line

Comment: You should run that one on a separate thread usually. most likely you are doing something wrong and it's giving an exception, you have to also catch exceptions.

Comment: No exception is being thrown.

Comment: Put code on separate thread also. Still hangs with no exception being thrown